# RxJs BehaviourSubject doesn't give its current value to forkJoin.pipe

Tags: rxjs

```
import { UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User } from 'oidc-client';

export class AuthService {
   private manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings(this.appSettingsService));

  private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  private get user(): Observable<User> { return this.userSubject.asObservable();}

  constructor(private appSettingsService: AppSettingsService) {
    this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userSubject.next(user);
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', user.access_token);
      }
    });
  }

  isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.user.pipe(map((user: User) => {
      return (user != null && !user.expired) || !!localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    }));

  get access_token(): Observable<string> {
    return this.user.pipe(map((u: User) => {
      if (u && u.access_token) {
        return u.access_token;
      }

      if (!!localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
        return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
      }

      return undefined;
    }));
  }

  isInRole(roleName: string): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log(`AuthService.isInRole ${roleName}`);
    return forkJoin({ isAuthenticated: this.isAuthenticated(), access_token: this.access_token })
      .pipe(map(fj => {
    console.log(`AuthService.isInRole.pipe ${roleName}`);
        if (!fj.isAuthenticated || !fj.access_token) {
          return false;
        }

        var claims: object = jwt_decode(fj.access_token);

        if ('role' in claims && claims['role'].indexOf(roleName) !== -1) {
          console.log(`AuthService.isInRole ${roleName} YES`);
          return true;
        }

        if ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' in claims
          && claims['http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role'].indexOf(roleName) !== -1
        ) {
          console.warn('Role claim type is ...microsoft...!');
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      }
      ));
  }
```

The message `AuthService.isInRole.pipe` never appears.
The `BehaviourSubject` was supposed to give its latest value when referenced, but this is not happening. Why?

Comment: `forkJoin` will only emit when all source observables complete.  Since your observables do not complete, you may want to try [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) or the [`withLastestFrom`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom) operator (*depending on the behavior you want*)

Comment: I keep seeing things about `combineLatest` being deprecated.

Comment: OK, so the probme is that `forkJoin` doesn't fire until _all_ of its observables have _completed_ and therefore I need to be using some other operator.  I want the current value, `combineLatest` sounds good except that -- apparently -- it is deprecated.

Comment: You can use `.pipe(take(1))` to get the source observable to emit a value and then complete. Where did you see that `combineLatest` is deprecated?

Comment: I think they deprecated passing separate source arguments. If you pass an object or array to combineLatrst, the warning should go away.